# Failed to load nodelet

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have been developing a nodelet of my own making reference to [kobuki](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki) project's safety controller package, however after I have successfully compiled my own package, I get the following error after launching my standalone nodelet manager and load in nodelet. I triple check if I have missed something but couldn't find anything wrong. I need a hand on how to compile a nodelet, HELP !

```
[ERROR] [1464333474.006836598]: Failed to load nodelet [/beebot_safety_controller] of type       [beebot_safety_controller/SafetyControllerNodelet] even after refreshing the cache: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class beebot_safety_controller/SafetyControllerNodelet with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist.
```

I filtered the rest of the irrelevant infos. And here are the essential backbone files of my package:
Launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" args="manager" />
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="beebot_safety_controller" 
    args="load beebot_safety_controller/SafetyControllerNodelet nodelet_manager">
  </node>
</launch>
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(range_proximity_safety_controller)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  nodelet
  pluginlib
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES range_proximity_safety_controller_nodelet
  CATKIN_DEPENDS nodelet roscpp rospy std_msgs pluginlib geometry_msgs 
)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 add_library(range_proximity_safety_controller_nodelet
   src/safety_controller.cpp
 )
 add_dependencies(range_proximity_safety_controller_nodelet
   ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
 )
 target_link_libraries(range_proximity_safety_controller_nodelet
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )

 install(TARGETS range_proximity_safety_controller_nodelet
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
 )

 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
 )

  install(DIRECTORY plugins
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
 )
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>range_proximity_safety_controller</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The range_proximity_safety_controller package</description>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  
  <build_depend>nodelet</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>  
    
  <run_depend>nodelet</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pluginlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>  

  <export>
    <nodelet pluginlib="${prefix}/plugins/nodelet_plugins.xml" />
  </export>
</package>
```

plugins/nodelet_plugins.xml:

```
<library path="lib/libbeebot_safety_controller_nodelet">
  <class name="beebot_safety_controller/SafetyControllerNodelet"
     type="beebot::SafetyControllerNodelet"
     base_class_type="nodelet::Nodelet">
    <description>
      Nodelet for Beebot's safety controller
    </description>  
    </class>
</library>
```

the header file:

```
#ifndef _SAFETY_CONTROLLER_H_
#define _SAFETY_CONTROLLER_H_

#include <string>
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace beebot
{
  class SafetyController
  {
  public:
    // some stuff
  private:
    //other stuff
  } ;  // Class definition

} // namespace

#endif
```

the cpp file:

```
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include "range_proximity_safety_controller/safety_controller.h"


namespace beebot{
  class SafetyControllerNodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet
  {
  public:
      // some stuff
  private:
      // other stuff
    
  } ; // class
} // namespace

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(beebot::SafetyControllerNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet) ;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235339/failed-to-load-nodelet/) by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2016-05-27**:
Could you also post your launch file?

**Comment by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on 2016-05-27**:
Thank you @Martin Peris, I added the launch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The nodelet_plugins.xml library path doesn't match your CMakeLists.txt library name.

```
<library path="lib/librange_proximity_safety_controller_nodelet">
```

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on 2016-05-28**:
Thank you for responding, @kmhallen. I switched the library name as you have given then deleted build and devel file under my workspace and recompiled.  but the error still persists. What could be the other reason?

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2017-06-08**:
So what was the issue? How was this fixed?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-10-03**:
@tanasis You should open a new question; Besides the comment section is not meant for new questions, questions asked in the comment section won't get as much attention.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2018-11-08**:
@130s it's not a *new* question. They're just asking for the actual solution because according to the first comment this answer does not seem to be it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same error happens when your package.xml is missing the line:

```
<exec_depend>nodelet</exec_depend>
```

I wanted to add this as another answer (even if it does not precisely solve the question at hand - the OP had this line in his code), since this question is the first hit when searching for "Failed to load nodelet".

---

Originally posted by [Germanunkol](https://answers.ros.org/users/36400/germanunkol/) with karma: 31 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2